# Как сделать появление надписи поверх фото?

Tags: html, img, css

Нужен код HTML CSS, что бы при наведении мыши на фотографию, поверх фотографии снизу появлялся невысокий прямоугольник с текстом, шириной как фотография.

Хочу что бы в новостях были просто фотографии, но если пользователь наведет мышкой на эти фотки появлялось пояснение к фото с сылкой.

Comment: @Михаил Затонский, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: я остановился на том что бы при наведении мыши изображение уменьшалось по длине, и хотел что бы дорисовывался черный прямоугольник на туже длину на которую уменьшалось изображение, и что бы на фоне него был текст. Но немогу сообразить как завершить.

Comment: конечно было бы здорово что бы визуально не просто жестко менялось, а выплывало...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="content">
        <img src="img/img.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="text"><a href="">Lorem Ipsum - це текст-"риба", що використовується в друкарстві та дизайні. Lorem Ipsum є, фактично, стандартною "рибою" аж з XVI сторіччя, коли невідомий друкар взяв шрифтову гранку та склав на ній підбірку зразків шрифтів. "Риба" не тільки успішно пережила п'ять століть, але й прижилася в електронному верстуванні, залишаючись по суті незмінною. Вона популяризувалась в 60-их роках минулого сторіччя завдяки виданню зразків шрифтів Letraset, які містили уривки з Lorem Ipsum, і вдруге - нещодавно завдяки програмам комп'ютерного верстування на кшталт Aldus Pagemaker, які використовували різні версії Lorem Ipsum.</a></div>
    </div>

    .text{
    display: none;
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;    
    padding: 20px;
    font: 14px/20px Tahoma;

}
.text a{    
    padding-top: 150px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;            
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

}
.content{
    position: relative;
    width: 545px;
    height: 525px;
    margin: 20px auto;

}
.content img{
    width: 545px;
    height: 525px;  
    border: 4px solid #ccc;
}
.content:hover .text{
    display: block; 
    width: 505px;
    height: 485px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 4px solid #ccc;     
}

.text a:hover{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /*-webkit-transform: scale(2);
 -moz-transform: scale(2);
 -o-transform: scale(2);*/
 /*-webkit-transform: translate(0,50px);
 -moz-transform: translate(0,50px);
 -o-transform: translate(0,50px);*/
}

<img src="img/img.jpg" alt="" /> - Ваша картинка!
```

Comment: не могу только сделать что бы снизу на картинке была рамочка, либо сверху либо убегает(